# How to make an array of UILabel in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

How do I make an array of UILabel in Swift. When I try to, I get an error like `ViewController.Type'dose not have a member named 'Lable00'`
my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let individualScores = [75, 43, 103, 87, 12]

    @IBOutlet var Lable00: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var Lable01: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var Lable02: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var Lable03: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var Lable04: UILabel?

    var Lable_Arr = [Lable00, Lable01, Lable02, Lable03, Lable04]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for score in individualScores {
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private var labels:[UILabel]()

override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    labels.append(Lable00)
    labels.append(Lable01)
    labels.append(Lable02)
    labels.append(Lable03)
    labels.append(Lable04)

    // do stuff with the labels view
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**for Swift 2 :**

```
var labels:[UILabel]=[]
```

Answer (score 2):

In ViewDid load you don't have to append, you can just assign a new array to labels like so:

```
var labels:[UILabel]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  labels = [label01, label02, label03, label04]

  // do stuff with the labels view
}
```